# What is the quickest way to update each row in one table with a use-once value from another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2017

I have a table called `dbo.RecycleProductID` that has just a primary key `ProductID` column and a `Used` column:

```
ProductID (pk, int) | Used (bit)
23                    1   
65                    1
68                    1
90                    NULL
104                   NULL  
...
60983471              NULL
```

The table above has about 6.5m `ProductID` values that need to be 'recycled' and assigned to products in a different table. Once a `ProductID` has been assigned to a product, I must update the `Used` column value to `1` to indicate it has been used. There are gaps in the `ProductID` sequence, some in the thousands (.e.g it can jump from 1010 to 8055) and there are way more rows in this table than the receiving table `dbo.Product` table.

The `dbo.Product` table (has about 1.5m rows) is just a list of products but with no `ProductID` values.

```
ProductID (pk, int)  | ProductName (varchar)
23                     Toothpaste
65                     Speakers
68                     Galaxy S8
NULL                   Plate
NULL                   Monitor
NULL                   Carpet
.....
```

I am currently running a while loop to get the `ProductID` values from `dbo.RecycleProductID` into the `dbo.Product` table:

```
DECLARE @Max int = (select max(ProductID) from [dbo].[RecycleProductID]);
DECLARE @Min int = (select min(ProductID) from [dbo].[RecycleProductID]);

while @Min <= @Max 
begin

UPDATE TOP (1)
[dbo].[Product]
SET ProductID = (SELECT TOP 1 ProductID FROM [dbo].[RecycleProductID] b1 WHERE b1.Used IS NULL ORDER BY ProductID ASC)
OUTPUT INSERTED.ProductID INTO dbo.UsedProductID
WHERE 
ProductID is null;

UPDATE  
    rp1
SET    
    rp1.Used = 1
FROM
    [dbo].[RecycleProductID] rp1
INNER JOIN
    dbo.UsedProductID ub1 ON 
    ub1.ProductID = rp1.ProductID

set @Min = @Min+1
end;
```

With this basically being a CURSOR, it is taking forever. It has been running for almost two days and only updated about 326515 rows. Is there a quicker way of doing this?

Comment: That cursor is updating every [RecycleProductID].[Used] on EVERY loop. No wonder it takes days.  set @Min = @Min+1Min is wrong if ProductID skips.

Comment: Try adding a [covering index](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/) to `dbo.RecycleProductID` that consists of `Used` and `ProductId` in that order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this query:

```
with t1 as (
    select
        ProducID, row_number() over (order by ProducID) rn
    from 
        RecycleProductID
    where
        used is null
)
, t2 as (
    select
        ProducID, row_number() over (order by ProducID) rn
    from 
        Product
    where
        ProductID is null
)

update t2
set t2.ProducID = t1.ProducID
from
    t2
    join t1 on t2.rn = t1.rn
```

EDIT: This query will update RecycleProductID and can be executed seperately

```
update RecycleProductID
set used = 1
where ProducID in (select ProductID from Product)
```

Comment: Exactly how I was going to suggest doing it. Don't forget to also update the RecycleProductId.Used column afterwards so that all of the Product IDs that have been reassigned are not used again if a similar operation is required in the future.

Comment: The `dbo.RecycleProductID` has more rows in it than the `dbo.Product` table. How will I update the `dbo.RecycleProductID` to set the `Used` column value to `1`?

Comment: The whole thing just ran in 33 seconds! Excellent solution.

Comment: An alternative for updating the `Used` column is to add an `output` clause to the initial `update` statement (`update t2 ...`) and capture the assigned `ProductId` values. They can then be used to update the `Used` values appropriately.

Comment: So after a little more usage of this SQL it is completely killing my SQL Server. I guess when the `Product` table was small it ran quickly but now there are millions of rows in the table with some having a `ProductID` assigned and some not, it is taking a long time to process and killing resources so other databases are inaccessible.

Comment: I'm only trying to update 80,770 rows in the `Product` table but even that has been running for more than an hour...

Comment: Why are you trying to use this script constantly? This should be used only one time. To correct data in tables. Then when inserting new data to `Product` take first unused `ProductID` and make updates in both tables

Comment: @uzi new products are coming in batches into the products table daily. If I run the CTE expressions individually they bring back the records within seconds, but as soon as it runs the `update t2
set t2.ProducID = t1.ProducID
from
    t2
    join t1 on t2.rn = t1.rn` statement the whole thing comes to a halt.

Comment: You are doing double work. I recommend rewrite your insert scripts so that `ProductId` would be inserted together...Do you have indexes on your tables? Try to rebuild them and update statistics

Comment: I can't write new ProductIDs until the existing ones are used up hence doing it this way until they are all `Used = 1`.

Comment: I am not suggesting you add new ProductIDs . Have a look at here, it might be more clearer http://rextester.com/KMBV99963

Comment: @uzi thank you for the example. i actually made it much quicker doing it in batches of 1000 rows. you can see my answer below

Answer (score 2):

Because MYSQL don't allow update on WITH, you can use this query to do the job on MYSQL :

```
with t1 as (
    select
        ProducID, row_number() over (order by ProducID) rn
    from 
        RecycleProductID
    where
        used is null
)
, t2 as (
    select
        ID, ProducID, row_number() over (order by ProducID) rn
    from 
        Product
    where
        ProductID is null
)

update Product t3
join t2 on t2.ID = t3.ID
join t1 on t1.rn = t2.rn

set t3.ProducID = t1.ProducID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the accepted solution
For the second update try

```
update RecycleProductID
set used = 1 
from RecycleProductID
join Product
  on RecycleProductID.ProductID = Product.ProductID  
 and used is null
```